# How to draw a number axis with arrow

Tags: manim

I need to draw a horizontal axis to decribe number, currently there is a NumberLine which can work, however there is no arrow to indicate the positive direction.

Is there built-in object to do that? or manually create such class with code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have doubts about how an object works, you can look for it in the source code `manimlib/mobject/`
In your case it is in number_line.py, the code is not difficult to understand and thus you avoid asking.

```py
class NumberLineExample(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        nl=NumberLine(x_min=-2,
                       x_max=2,
                       include_numbers=True,
                       include_tip=True,
                       label_direction=UP
                      )

        self.add(nl)
```

If you see the source code you find all options:

```py
class NumberLine(Line):
    CONFIG = {
        "color": LIGHT_GREY,
        "x_min": -FRAME_X_RADIUS,
        "x_max": FRAME_X_RADIUS,
        "unit_size": 1,
        "include_ticks": True,
        "tick_size": 0.1,
        "tick_frequency": 1,
        # Defaults to value near x_min s.t. 0 is a tick
        # TODO, rename this
        "leftmost_tick": None,
        # Change name
        "numbers_with_elongated_ticks": [0],
        "include_numbers": False,
        "numbers_to_show": None,
        "longer_tick_multiple": 2,
        "number_at_center": 0,
        "number_scale_val": 0.75,
        "label_direction": DOWN,
        "line_to_number_buff": MED_SMALL_BUFF,
        "include_tip": False,
        "tip_width": 0.25,
        "tip_height": 0.25,
        "decimal_number_config": {
            "num_decimal_places": 0,
        },
        "exclude_zero_from_default_numbers": False,
    }
```